# Is there any tool available by which one can calculate (a)the size or a single row in sqlserver (b)the amount of traffic hitting the sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance

Is there any tool available by which one can calculate the size or a single row in sqlserver. This would really help in calculating the expected size of DB. Further one option can be to use sp_spaceused but it gives the details of the whole table... what we want is the size of a record (maximum size) in a table.

Further is there any tool to check the amount of traffic that is hitting the server so as to enable to identify the bottlenecks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Come on, don't change your question into a multi-parter... I answered the question you asked, it's only polite to accept that answer if it's correct.  It only takes a second to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a tool for this, it's a very simple query to write:

```
SELECT SUM(length)
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
```

Comment: This is giving a value like '67' in result. Is this the size of the row in KB or something else ?

Comment: @HotTester: Individual row sizes are always in bytes.  The size can never be more than 8060 bytes (slightly less than 8 KB).

Comment: This puzzles me.. say if i am saving a picture (size 200kb) in a row then wouldn't the size would increase beyond 8 KB of the row ?

Comment: @HotTester: Columns like `varchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` are not in-row data, they are LOB data stored outside the row.  P.S. please don't store images in your database unless you are using SQL 2008's `FILESTREAM` type, it will lead to poor performance.